# Inconsistent 503 Service Unavailable using src.sencha.io

Tags: extjs, retina-display, image-resizing

The product I am referring to is [src.sencha.io](https://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/). You pass the path of your image into a src.sench.io url, pass some parameters and your image is resized dynamically. I have been receiving 503's inconsistently.

I have tweeted to Sencha, tried to write on their forums with no avail. I was hoping the community on StackOverflow could shed some light on the service. I am currently using the service in production, so you can imagine the amount of complaints received.

Will this service be maintained in the future and are there any workarounds at the moment? I would prefer not to pull the service entirely. You can imagine my frustration as a developer. I will be sure to never use any Sencha products in the future if this is how they choose to communicate with their developers, free or paid.

Are there any other similar services around that provide image resizing and retina support on the fly. I do not mind paying for the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my fallback answer which doesn't directly address the question, I haven't used it myself, but keep coming across [ReSRC](http://www.resrc.it/).

Another similar looking one is [responsive.io](https://responsive.io/).

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/) also has a good write up of many possibilities, under *Do I care about relying on third parties?*

Answer (score 1):

I also use the service and have had this problem. I've written a graceful JavaScript fallback you may be interested in using:

https://github.com/ultrapasty/sencha-src-image-fallback

It falls back to local SRCs if src.sencha.io returns an error on the first request. Feel free to take, use, modify etc.

Comment: Thanks Zougen. I will definitely take a look. Just wondering if this service is / going to still be supported.

Comment: So am I! Keep us posted...

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd drop a message on here as it definitely adds value to the post for anyone looking at using [ReSRC](http://www.resrc.it). If you fancy 50% off the first 3 months on a small or medium plan just enter 'halfprice-small' or 'halfprice-medium on checkout.

Cheers
Dom (ReSRC, Co-Founder)